# ReactJS/Apollo/Graphql: Block data.refetch w/ @skip until onSubmit is clicked but have refetch still available

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

After some debugging, I found out that when the page loads, @skip is doing what I want which is blocking the execution of the query on page loading. However, when the submit button is clicked the app crashes.

I do not understand why the start and end are undefined?

`variables: {start: undefined, end: undefined, skipFi: true}`

If I remove `skipF: true` from following the app works fine:

```
export default graphql(getObjQ, { 
    options: (props) => ({ 
        variables: { 
            start: props.start,
            end: props.end,
            skipF: true

        } 
    })         
)(Comp);
```

I am trying to apply the concept from h[ere](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/289) to my app:

```
 export default graphql(gql`
        query SearchQuery($query: String, $first: Int, $skip: Boolean!) {
            search(query: $query, first: $first) @skip(if: $skip) {
                edges {
                    ....
                }
            }
        }
    `,  { options: {variables: { skip: true } }})(Input);
```

The handleSubmit function looks like this:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();



        this.setState({
          errMsg: "",
          start: new Date(document.getElementById("start").value).valueOf(),
          end: new Date(document.getElementById("end").value).valueOf(),
          submit: true,




        }, () => {
          this.props.data.refetch({
            start: this.state.start,
            end:this.state.end,


          });
```

The query looks like this which is in a separate file/component:

```
    const Query =gql`
      query getObjQ($start: Float!, $end: Float!, $skipF: Boolean!

) 

  {

    abs(start: $start,  end:$end) @skip(if: $skipF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many 'moving parts' - try hardcoded values first:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.props.data.refetch({
    start: XXXXXXXXXXX,
    end: YYYYYYYYY,
    skipF: false
  });
}
```

UPDATE:

method for debugging `options` parameters (return object):

```
export default graphql(getObjQ, { 
  options: (props) => {
    console.log(props.start);
    return { 
      variables: { 
        start: props.start,
        end: props.end,
        skipF: true
      } 
    }
  }
})(Comp);
```

Comment: Still getting: `variables: {start: undefined, end: undefined, skipFi: true}`

Comment: console.log just after, `options: (props) => ({ ` is good. So it looks like I have the wrong syntax for passing `skipF: true`.